# How to replace a file in a zip

Tags: java, zip

I'm working with `*.jar` files, as far as I understand it's an archive format I can manipulate with standard tools like `zip` or `unzip` commands.

I often need to replace a file already compressed. So far I unzip, delete the old file, move the new one at the good place (it's a source archive, so it's **hightly layered**), and then I re-compressed it.

Is it possible to do it more quickly? It would be 3 informations : the file to replace, the target archive in which to replace, and the path to the file to be replaced into the archive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799553/how-to-update-one-file-in-a-zip-archive

Comment: @Kamaraj my file to replace has not the same structure and not the same name that the file to be replaced. Should I create up to 10 folder just to get the same structure?

Comment: So basically, you are asking for an easy way to remove and add files to an existing archive without manual de-/re-compression. **Replacing** a specific file is only a subset of what you are really asking, so you might want to edit your title and question. Please add new information always to the answer, not via comments. Flag my comment as obsolete afterwards.

Comment: It’s worth noting that, while JAR files are ZIP files, there are added subtleties (*e.g.*, the order of the manifest) which mean that in some cases, using `zip` to manipulate them will break them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two steps:

```
zip -d myjar.jar path/to/file/to/delete
jar uf myjar.jar -C base/path path/to/file/to/add
```

You can ignore the `-C base/path` part if you’re already in the base directory (containing `path/to/file/to/add`).

When working with JARs rather than plain ZIP files, you should get into the habit of using `jar` rather than `zip` as far as possible; it ensures the manifest is stored correctly.

With a plain ZIP file, you can add or update a file simply by (re-)archiving it; so instead of the `jar` command above, use:

```
zip myzip.zip path/to/file/to/add
```

You need to be in the base directory for this to work. (`jar` will work too but it’s odd to require `jar` when working with ZIP files.)

Comment: Nice, but it seems to be jar specific. Is there something similar if I need to replace a file into a zip or gzip archive?

Comment: See my update. `gzip` doesn’t archive files; presumably you’re talking about tarballs, `tar` has similar options.